# Move documents from a SharePoint services 3.0 site to a SharePoint 2010 site with the document version history

Tags: 2010, wss-3.0, migration

We are currently looking into migrating our existing document library that is using SharePoint services 3.0 to a SharePoint 2010 document library setup within TFS. Is there any possible way to move the documents over whilst retaining the existing version history?

Answer (score 1):

- The Fast and proper way to move a list is moving it with a third
  party tool. The advantage with the third party tools is that they are
  very simple, and they work well. The Downside, of course is that they
  are not freeJ. However, I am sure that if you only want to move a
  list, you can simply download a trial and get the work done. Here is
  the one I heard the most positive comments about.
  [ShareGate](http://yourock.share-gate.com/sharegate-sharepoint-migration-management-tool/?utm_source=OnlineAdvertising&utm_medium=Banner&utm_campaign=SharePointAds) >> They offer a 15 day free Trial. for one or two library 15 days enough. There are other tools as well which offer free trial i.e metalogix etc.
- Another way is database migration,[read this step by step guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff959273(v=WS.10).aspx)
- another method is change the .cab file, i am not sure wheather its work for wss3.0 to 2010 but you can try it. [follow the instruction on this link, Method 1](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve versions, you can look at one of the migration tools on the market (AvePoint has a great toolset), or you can do a database attach/upgrade of the 2007 content database into the 2010 environment. Obviously the third party tool option would have a cost associated with it, but the database attach method wouldn't.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93e7cc06-db94-41ca-a590-e2c158d7a7e3/sharepoint-2007-to-2010-document-library-migration